# Perturbation Method in Mechanics: Average velocity of a small mass on a vibrating inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, perturbation-theory

I've stumbled across this delightful and difficult collection of problems, by Jaan Kalda. The following problem has stumped me. (It's probem 16 on the sheet, which I have provided as a link)

http://www.ioc.ee/~kalda/ipho/meh_ENG.pdf

> A block is situated on a slope with angle $\alpha$, the coefficient of friction between them is $\mu > \tan \alpha$. The slope is rapidly driven back and forth in  away that it's velocity vector $\vec{u}$ is parallel to both the slope and the horizontal and has constant modulus $v$; the direction of $\vec{u}$ reverses abruptly after each time interval $\tau$. What will be the average velocity $w$ of the block's motion? Assume $g\tau \ll v.$

[image: diagram]

The author also enlists some relevant and helpful ideas, which I'm not listing here but one of them has to do with perturbation method. He also mentions that the last assumption means that the block's velocity doesn't change much in the time interval $\tau$, so the zeroth approximation is that of a block moving in a straight line with constant velocity.
He then says that we can calculate the average value of the frictional force based on the motion obtained in the zeroth case.

I don't understand how that can be done, so any hint or idea would be immensely helpful. I've been trying this problem for 2 months now and just to ensure that I am not missing some maths, I've gone and read perturbation theory, but it hasn't been of any help.

How do I proceed now?

The answer given, is $\frac{v}{\sqrt{\mu^2 \cot^2 \alpha -1}}$.

Comment: Hi Aritra and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a help site for homework or exercises. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: @JohnRennie I know that, but I don't really want help on this particular problem. Maybe I couldn't make it clear enough, but what I really want is some insight into how perturbation method applies to mechanics problems, apart from the classic examples (like the ones about gravitational orbits).

Comment: @Aritra - I'm a bit suspicious of the answer given. It contains the shaking velocity v, the coefficient of friction, and the slope angle BUT it doesn't contain the gravitational acceleration g. Doesn't that strike you as strange? It seems that the answer is saying that the average velocity of the block would be the same if the exact same experiment were performed on either the Earth or the Moon or a planet with hardly any gravity at all. I find that hard to believe.

Comment: @SamuelWeir I think you should visit the link I provided, and have a look at the things mentioned after the problem. There were some comments about disregarding the acceleration due to gravity as $\tau$ is quite small with respect to $\frac{v}{g}$. Maybe that's why $g$ is totally absent from the answer.

Comment: @AritraDas - But that doesn't make sense. Gravity after all is the ultimate driving force in determining which way the block travels across the plane, right? So how could the magnitude of g be totally absent? As for the stated assumption that tg<<v, that's not violated in considering smaller and smaller g's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that, roughly speaking, the block moves down the gradient of the slope.

Because the slope changes its direction of motion, it pushes the block left and right in roughly equal measure, and because it has a short period, the block never moves with significant horizontal velocity relative to the fixed axes. Thus, the horizontal speed of the block relative to the plane is always approximately $v$ and the average horizontal velocity is zero.

The velocity in the direction of the gradient may vary a small amount, but let us simply work with the average, $w$. The component of friction pointing up the gradient must be $F_w = m g \sin\alpha$ to prevent the block from accelerating. The friction force points opposite the velocity, so $\frac{F_x}{F_w} = \frac{v}{w}$.

Meanwhile, the friction force is $F = \mu N = \mu m g \cos\alpha$. Using $F^2 = F_x^2 + F_w^2$ we can eliminate the forces algebraically to find the answer you quoted.

Comment: Why should the velocity go back to zero? And I think we have to ignore the $g \cos \alpha \tau$ change in velocity and that is the perturbed problem. Also, the answer given is  $\frac{v}{\sqrt{\mu^2 \cot^2 \alpha -1}}$.

Comment: @AritraDas Yes, I see I made a mistake before, and have updated the answer. I still don't see a need for perturbation theory.

Comment: Very nice solution. I was skeptical about perturbation theory too, but maybe there is another way of thinking about it which involves some perturbation. If there is, I'd be glad to see it.

Comment: One second, why is $F_y = mg\sin \alpha$ ?

Comment: Because that's the component from the normal force pointing down the plane. I changed the notation as $F_y$ was not the force in the $y$ direction.

Comment: I would like to explicitly see how g, the acceleration due gravity, drops out of the expression for the average velocity of the block as claimed by the official answer at the linked website. I don't buy the official answer at the linked website. It just doesn't look right.

Comment: The answer already shows that explicitly by providing a complete solution.

Comment: @MarkEichenlaub I mean, why should the block not accelerate downwards? And if friction really is always $mg\sin \alpha$ up the incline, then why does the block move downward at all? (How does it start moving?)

Comment: @MarkEichenlaub - I disagree. It is not apparent at all that g drops out of the solution from what you wrote. You have a factor of g in F, and a factor of g in Fu. I don't see any mention of what Fx is equal to. How does g drop out when you solve for w?

Comment: @Samuel, please just do the algebra. There are two expressions containing $F_x$. It can be eliminated.

Comment: Aritra, the answer describes the steady-state solution. There is a transient period during which this analysis does not hold. The block begins sliding because initially, before the shaking begins, the block does not move. Once the slope starts shaking, the block moves horizontally because frictions pushes it. But the friction force is then exactly horizontal, so the gravitational force is unopposed and pulls the block down the plane. It accelerates down the gradient until it gets to $w$.

Comment: @MarkEichenlaub - OK, my apologies about the g. It does drop out of the solution and your solution does match the officially stated solution. I still remain suspicious about the fact that g does drop out, though. Can you provide any insight as to why the magnitude of g doesn't matter when after all the direction of g is ultimately determining the direction of the average block velocity on the plane?

Comment: Samuel, maybe it will help to note that if you reduce $g$, you'll make the transient period longer. The condition on the final velocity is basically kinematic. The friction force is fixed and larger than the force required to hold the block up. Therefore, the block zig-zags such that it isn't falling straight down the slope. The final velocity is derived from how much zig-zag there is in the steady state. In the steady state, reducing $g$ reduces the force from friction and the force required to stop acceleration down the gradient by the same factor, leaving the kinematic condition unchanged.

Comment: @MarkEichenlaub - I see, so the direction of g does have an effect but the magnitude of g doesn't. Interesting. Thanks, nice analysis.

Comment: @Samuel Thanks for getting me to think about it a bit more!